# Capital distribution between several bets

Tags: probability

I'm trying to figure out the algorithm of capital distribution between several bets.

For example, let's say I have two bets with the same 50%/50% probability of winning and losing, but one bet has a higher expected value, i.e. the first bet could win or lose 10 and a second could win 15, but lose the same 10.

So the question is, how should I distribute the capital between these two bets if I want to maximize the probable return of the portfolio?

I tried to calculate the expected value of the weighted bets portfolio, but this method doesn't make sense (or I'm doing something wrong), because it basically says "put all your money in the bet with highest expected value", and if two bets have the same expected value, it doesn't show that I need to allocate 50% of capital to each of them.  [image]

Comment: If you want to maximize the expectation, then put all your money into the option with the largest expectation!  That this might not seem so obvious may be due to the fact that people weigh more than the expectation when betting: they often want to balance the *risk.*  By ignoring that, you have a trivial problem with a trivial solution.